# restore firewall public network policy using a command

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script to secure some machines by blocking all incoming connections using the following command, which works great:

```
netsh advfirewall set publicprofile firewallpolicy blockinboundalways,allowoutbound
```

However, when I try to restore using:

```
netsh advfirewall set publicprofile firewallpolicy notconfigured,notconfigured
```

I get "Notconfigured value can only be used when configuring a Group Policy object (GPO) store. "

Any idea which command should I use to restore the fist commands results into its original state?

Comment: netsh advfirewall reset

Comment: I have also found that "netsh advfirewall set publicprofile firewallpolicy blockinbound,allowoutbound" resolved my problem of not being able to connect in any way whatsoever.